# Pip Install Theano Error Code 255

Tags: python, pip, theano, setup.py

I am trying to install Theano on my Windows 10 system with Python 2.7.9, 64-bit through `pip install theano`. But I am getting a crash every time with this message:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 255 in
>   c:\users\sunny\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-lwmpfg\theano\

And then a window says `python.exe has stopped working`.

What is wrong with my system and how to install Theano on a Windows system? Please see Edit 2 too!

Edit: This is the complete terminal instance

```
C:\Users\sunny>pip install theano
Collecting theano
  Using cached Theano-0.8.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info\Theano.egg-info
    writing requirements to pip-egg-info\Theano.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing pip-egg-info\Theano.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info\Theano.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info\Theano.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\Theano.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'pip-egg-info\Theano.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: manifest_maker: MANIFEST.in, line 9: 'recursive-include' expects <dir> <pattern1> <pattern2> ...

    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\Theano.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 255 in c:\users\sunny\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-dwordf\theano\

C:\Users\sunny>
```

Edit 2: It seems like `pip install` command itself is problematic, since using it gives `python.exe has stopped working` irrespective of the package

```
C:\Users\sunny>pip install django
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django in c:\users\sunny\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages

C:\Users\sunny>
```

Comment: Can you post the output you get before the crash?

Comment: @phihag I have added that now!

Comment: I have to switch between pip installer and mini conda. For the ones that give issues for pip this usually works http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html give it a try!

Comment: @vikingben I will report back as soon as I try it!